# Is there any cool method to define/calc PI using lazy evaluation sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I use lazy.js on javascript.

I wonder if there's a cool method to define (not actually calc) PI empowered by lazy evaluation.

I know lazy-evaluation is call-by-need, but how do you define PI in the lazy eval code?

For instance, we can define Natural number infinite sequence in lazy.js:

```
var _ = Lazy; 
var natural = function(n)
{
  return n;
};

var _natural = _.generate(natural);
```

Of course, since it's call-by-need, you can obtain only a part of the natural numbers like

```
var n100 = _natural.take(100).toArray();
```

Any way to define PI like natural number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cool method to calculate pi lazily by unfolding an infinite stream of successive approximations. These are the so-called "unbounded spigot" algorithms (unbounded as they exploit laziness to yield infinite streams of better answers).

See [Jeremy Gibbon's paper](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf), where a (deliberately obscure) example is given:

```
pi = g(1,0,1,1,3,3) where
 g(q,r,t,k,n,l) =
  if 4*q+r-t<n*t
  then n : g(10*q,10*(r-n*t),t,k,div(10*(3*q+r))t-10*n,l)
  else g(q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,div(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)(t*l),l+2)
```